# SAPUI5 TypeError: this.nav.to is not a function

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to `SAPUI5`

I'm trying to show the master page when a Tile is clicked in a home page. Below is the code that I have used with in event handler.

```
var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext();
this.nav.to("Master", context);
```

The problem here is I am getting following error **TypeError: this.nav.to is not a function**

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

What is `this` in your context? That depends on where your `tilePressed` method is defined. If it's defined in a controller, `this` will refer to the controller. 
If it is defined statically - you often find this for formatter functions - this will refer to the control that triggered the event.

Is the variable `this.nav` defined and appropriatly initialized? It needs to contain some kind of [`NavContainer`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html) e.g. the outermost `sap.m.App` resp. `sap.m.SplitApp`.

Also check out this [article on the usage of this in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and this very handy jQuery function [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

Answer (score 1):

> The `this.nav.to()` and `this.nav.back()` functions are not
>   defined in the App.controller.js. You need to write the following code
>   in `App.controller.js` so that the compiler identifies the functions
>   being called.

```
to : function (pageId, context) {

    var app = this.getView().app;

    // load page on demand
    var master = ("Master" === pageId);
    if (app.getPage(pageId, master) === null) {
        var page = sap.ui.view({
            id : pageId,
            viewName : "ProjectPath.view." + pageId,
            type : "XML"
        });
        page.getController().nav = this;
        app.addPage(page, master);
        jQuery.sap.log.info("app controller > loaded page: " + pageId);
    }

    // show the page
    app.to(pageId);

    // set data context on the page
    if (context) {
        var page = app.getPage(pageId);
        page.setBindingContext(context);
    }
},

back : function (pageId) {
    this.getView().app.backToPage(pageId);
}
```